# Is there any process to determine what elements a physical sample is made from?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I'm wondering if anyone knows of laboratory services that can analyze a sediment sample to tell what it's made of.

Background: our drinking water has small black flakes appearing, and our city water department cannot tell us what they are, and they say they have no equipment to test it. Their guess is either manganese, or sediment.

I'm not sure if there's a way to test an arbitrary sample to determine what it is. I've tried a few labs but none of them have the ability to do something like that.

Comment: You would need several techniques. An  atomic absorption spectrometer would be good for manganese, but for "sediment" (very broad), there is no telling. Chromatography of some sort + mass spec would be my first guess for general dirt, but maybe not. You could always do elemental analysis, but if it's not a pure sample, that won't help with IDing a specific compound, but elements would be easy enough. Honestly, without more than "sediment," you're going to have a hard time getting a concrete identification.

Comment: There are certainly techniques that can analyze one or a small number of particulates. A scanning electron microscopy with an x-ray detector (SEM/EDS) would be my first thought. X-ray diffraction (XRD) and perhaps x-ray fluorescence (XRF) are others. // I'm sure that after Flint everyone is nervous about their water. In general I'd be more worried about the stuff in the water that I couldn't see. Pb+2 would be invisible to the eye.

Comment: I could suggest checking with you neighbors to see if they have the same problem. Also a simple particulate filter in the kitchen would keep such particulates out of your food. // I'd wonder if you have an old iron supply line coming into your house that has corroded. The water flow through such a line is strong enough to break of chunks of the crud.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the info, it's been a big help. It seems like it might be "scale" build up in our tank-less hot water system. Called the manufacturer as a guess, and they said it can happen when the water gets heated and reacts with whatever particular elements are in our water source. I wouldn't have guessed anything could solidify in this manner while passing through a tankless system, but that's what they said. Sorry to transform the chem board into a home improvement board.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well if the tankless hot-water is to blame that is easy to test. Filter some cold water through a coffee filter and filter some hot water through a coffee filter - may need to run for a while. I'd guess that the "shock" of going from no flow to full bore open would be more likely to dislodge crud. // PS - Did you know that you get crude forming a ppt in the bottom of a hot water tank? You're suppose to flush the ppt out once in a while.

Comment: Look for labs with ion chromatography (metals), electron capture chromatography (halogenated compounds), and gas chromatography/mass spectrometry (organic compounds). They should be common.